# Read realtime output of a command

Tags: java, android

How can I read real-time output of a shell command from Java

This is what I have so far but it prints after command has been executed:

```
try {
    proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("du -d 1 /sdcard/");

    InputStream inputStream = proc.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        publishProgress(i);
        i++;
        System.out.println(line); // it prints all at once after command has been executed.
    }
}
catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e("du","error "+e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Btw where do you see the output of `System.out.println` ?

Comment: Is there only one line in your output?

Comment: `du` is very fast. Yet ,did you try with ProcessBuilder and Process.start ?

Comment: @pedja In LogCat you see the output of `Log` methods, not `System.out.println`

Comment: No. its command `du` from linux. Scans entire folder and display size

Comment: @fiddler it prints also System.out.println

Comment: @pedja oh you're talking about the deprecated LogCat view then

Comment: `System.out.println` isnt the problem. Same happens with updating ui in `onProgressUpdate`

Comment: I tested your code on Windows, it prints output immediately

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
try {
 proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("du -d 1 /sdcard/");

 InputStream inputStream = proc.getInputStream();
 InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
 BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

 while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line); // it prints all at once after command has been executed.
 }
 proc.waitFor();
}
catch (IOException e) {
 Log.e("du","error "+e.getMessage());
}
```